# Jquery scroll animation jumpy on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll

I'm having issues with jquery animate() to auto scroll a page to a desired div when the corresponding link is clicked.  It works perfectly in FF and Safari but in chrome, on click the view jumps to the div and back to its original position really quickly (maybe a 100ms) and then proceeds to scroll to the relevant div as desired.  I've seen posts out there with jquery being jumpy but not specifically on chrome when other browsers are unaffected.

Here is the JS

```
function initialize_autoscroll(){
  //Auto Scrolling Based on clicked links
  $('#home_button').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
     });

  $('#features_button').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({  scrollTop: $("#features").offset().top -50}, 700);
  });

  $('#examples_button').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({   scrollTop: $("#examples").offset().top -50}, 700);
  });

  $('#pricing_button').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({  scrollTop: $("#pricing").offset().top -50}, 700);
  });

  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  initialize_autoscroll();
});
```

Here is a sample a tag that fires the scrolling functionality

```
<a id="features_button" href="#features"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Features</a>
```

Here is a sample div that it links to:

```
<div id="features" class="container-narrow" style="padding-bottom:50px">
</div
```

Comment: have you tried with `slow` instead of `700`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default action in all your `#anchors` bindings using [`Event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). For example,

```
$('#home_button').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
});
```